# Solve $x^2y^2y'''=2y^2y'-3xy(y')^2+x^2(y')^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2y^2y'''=2y^2y'-3xy(y')^2+x^2(y')^3$$
What I did was to use $p=xy'$ and $p'=\frac{dp}{dy}$ to obtain
$$y^2(p(p')^2+p^2p''-2pp'-p^2p')=3yp^2+p^3 $$
Which reduces third order non-linear ODE to second order non-linear equation. But after this I'm stuck. I, again, tried to apply $q=yp'$ and $q=\frac{p'}{y}$ but, this time $y$ did not disappear as in the case of $x$'s.

Any hint and reference is appreciated.

Comment: By inspection, it looks like $y=x^n$ is a solution.

Comment: Define $v$ by $y=e^{\int v(x)\ dx}$, and you'll get $x^2 (v'' +3vv') = 2v - 3xv^2$. If you let $u = xy'/y = vx$,  you'll get $xu'' + 3uu' - 2u = 0$. I hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

Such an inspection in the comments works because the ODE is homogenous in $x$. To rigorously obtain the equivalent ODE to solve, use the  substitution $$x = e^t$$ to obtain $$-3y^2\ddot{y}+y^2\dddot{y}=-3(\dot{y})^2+(\dot{y})^3$$ where each dot represents a time derivative. This ODE does not seem to have an obvious solution, though you might be able to solve this numerically. A further reduction of order can be made by considering the substitution
$$\dot{y} = u(y)$$
where $u(\cdot)$ is an unknown function to be solved. The resulting ODE is a little too complicated so I've left it out.

A good reference for solving ODE analytically (if possible) would be [https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Mathematical-Methods-Scientists-Engineers/dp/0387989315](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387989315).